# Chrome Browser extensions development

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have been creating a google chrome browser extension I have been trying to find out how to get the URL of the current tab. after doing a bunch of research I came up with this small code that should print the current URL in the console here is the code.

`chrome.tabs.getCurrent()
{
 console.log(tab.url);
}`

But it does not work 
by the way, this code should run when the user clicks on the extension icon

Comment: Where are you running this code? Have you packaged extension ? What tutorial you are using (if any) ?

Comment: This code is written in a javascript file and is been called by an HTML file. and I have not packaged the extension and I am not using any tutorial at the moment.

Comment: Find a tutorial, read it, then get back with real questions. // TL;DR - the code you are showing will not run from html, it is a priviledged code which needs access to extension API

Comment: Use chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, tabs => { const activeTab = tabs[0]; /* do something */ });

Comment: Thanks, wOxxOm this kinda off works the problem I have is on the console it displays a list of information about the current tab. how do I extract the URL information from that list? For example, how could I print just the URL in the console or display it in an HTML file? thanks